# Get distinct value from database

Tags: linq, entity-framework, oracle11g

I want to get the distinct list of `studentname` from the database who are still active. Ihis is what I've tried.

```
string strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
     context.Students.Where(x => x.IsActive == 1).Distinct().ToList());
```

Comment: Could you please desribe your problem more detailed? Show us your table structure / (example) data and give information about expected result.

Comment: are you want only studentname list???

Comment: @SHAIL SHARMA What your query _returns_  now?

Comment: My query returning me repeated student name from the database. I just want a student with not repeated student name like( select distinct name from table-name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distinct function works on all columns, so I assume that you want only student name.

```
string strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    context
        .Students
        .Where(x => x.IsActive==1)
        .Select(x=>x.StudentName)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList()
 );
```